# Why won't this delegated version of jQuery's .on work right?

Tags: javascript, jquery, select2-rails

When I run this code, I do not get the simple `alert`. I delegated it    to the `body` because the element does not exist in the DOM on page      load, it is dynamically generated after clicking on a dropdown via       https://github.com/argerim/select2-rails.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('body').on('click', ".select2-highlighted", function() {
    alert("derp");
  });
});
```

As always, I appreciate any help! Even telling me I suck and to re-read the docs and troubleshoot it more! But please no downvotes without giving me some advice :/

## EDIT

Sorry everyone, I did not know that the select2 library I was using had [events](http://select2.github.io/select2/#events) that I could bind to. I just started my job a few months ago and inherited a large codebase, part of which is select2, so I dug into the docs today.

**Thanks again to `Pointy`, `A. Wolff`, `Kresimir Pendic`, `charlietfl` for getting me started down the road to the fix!**

Comment: You really have not posted enough code for anybody to help. The code you posted would work fine, assuming your clicked element actually has the class "select2-highlighted".

Comment: @Pointy Hey that's what comments are for. I'll add a screenshot of the Chrome element inspector? Sorry for the subpar post - I'm not on here much!

Comment: And assuming that you don't stop event propagation before it reachs `document` level

Comment: hey hey,, are you sure that it the correct class that you need to target?

Comment: Since you're using that fancy add-on tool (select2), another possibility is that an event handler that's part of that code is getting to the event first and stopping its propagation.

Comment: In case of event propagation stopped by plugin, capture event instead: `document.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
    if ($(event.target).closest('.select2-highlighted').length) { 
        alert("derp");
    }
}, true /*Capture event*/);`. It works for dynamic elements too and is fired before bubbling phase

Comment: @A.Wolff didn't think about that.

Comment: @Pointy has a good thought that it could be getting stopped by the gem.

Comment: EDIT typo: in first comment, i meant `body` level, not `document`

Comment: If that "select2" thing uses some outer wrapper element (maybe with class "select2" or something useful like that), you could try setting up the delegation with the selector ".select2 *", just as an experiment. Or use your own wrapper `<div class='select2-test'>`.

Comment: @A.Wolff I am going to copy and paste your code into RubyMine so I can see how it's broken down and what it's doing and then let you know what it returns!

Comment: There is probably an event hook in the select2 plugin api you can tap into to do whatever it is you need

Comment: @A.Wolff thank you for helping today!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This worked for me in the past (for dinamicaly added forms) that I attached `select2` component on

```
$( elem ).on( 'select2-open', function(){ // ... });
```

so I guess if you are on version 3.x and not new v4 that you can similary do:

```
$( elem ).on( 'select2-highlight', function(){ //.. });
```

here is the page that has that event documented: http://select2.github.io/select2/

Comment: Doesn't the first argument passed to `on` have to be the type of event?

Comment: @RudyOnRails Have a look at posted link documentation, there is some exmples. And ya, first parameter is the type of event, here it is a custom event

Comment: @A.Wolff ahhhh, I did not know there were custom events! Someone in the museum community just let me know that they had an issue similar to this and need to bind to the `select2:select` event.

Comment: Thanks Kresimir - I had been on https://select2.org/programmatic-control/events which a colleague in the museum industry had directed me towards, but I didn't check what version I had, which was `3.5.4`, so `select2:select` was not working! After I got version right, your doc link helped me out! `select2-selecting` for the win :)